# Logcat no longer accepts empty tags

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-log

I couldn't figure out why my Logs weren't printing to the Logcat, until I added a tag. I'm lazy when it comes to logging and never added tags in the past. It's been a while since I've done android work, so I'm not sure how long its been this way. Why can I no longer do this, and is there a way to make it work again? I could just as easily make my own method to print logs, but I'm looking if there is a setting I can change to make it work the way it used to.

```
Log.i("", "This is how i like it"); //Doesn't work

Log.i("Pointless Tag", "This is not how i like it"); //Works
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same tag to everything (I use my name as mine).  Not putting in a tag is ok for debug code, but it makes everything harder to parse for every other developer if one sneaks into release.

Answer (score 0):

The logs with empty tag are actually there, you can see them using `adb logcat`. But for some reason Android Studio strips log messages with empty tag. Looks like a bug in Android Studio.