# How to get Signature of a Apk?

Tags: java, android, signature

Is there any way to get the Signature of any installed apk using Java.

I tried this code but it is not working

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    String sign = pInfo.signatures[0].toString();
    sig.setText(sign);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("",e.toString());
 
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Please help me, i am new to Android Development

Comment: Please explain in detail what "it is not working" means. What are your results?

Comment: Firstly, `catch`ing `Exception`s isn't a good practice. Secondly, I am not sure what your error is, but [android studio won't show logs with empty tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351074/logcat-no-longer-accepts-empty-tags), therefore, you should use `e.printStacktrace()` to see the stacktrace instead

Comment: It returning android.content.pm.Signature@2b6cb416.

Comment: Error is that the signature[0] returning android.content.pm.Signature@2b6cb416.